# How to symmetrize a given function (U-statistics)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, asymptotics

Van der Vaart's "Asymptotic Statistics" (Ch 12) contains the quote:

> Given a known function $h$, consider the estimation of the "parameter" $$\theta = Eh(X_{1},\cdots,X_{r})$$ In order to simplify the formulas, it is assumed that the function $h$ is permutation-symmetric in its $r$ arguments. **(A given $h$ can always be replaced by a symmetric one)**.

Given any function $h$, how can we find its permutation-symmetric equivalent?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetrization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

whuber's comment has basically provided the answer to the question, but here's a slightly more detailed answer:

For simplicity consider a U-statistic of order 2 with kernel $h$, i.e. we want to estimate

$$ \theta = \mathbb E[h(X_1, X_2)] $$

Now also consider the function $$\tilde{h}(x,y) := \frac{h(x,y) + h(y,x)}{2}$$

If $h$ was symmetric to begin with, then $\tilde{h}=h$. However, even if $h$ is not symmetric, $\tilde{h}$ is symmetric and furthermore, with $X_1, X_2$ i.i.d., we have:

$$\mathbb E[\tilde{h}(X_1,X_2)] = \frac{\mathbb E[h(X_1,X_2)] + \mathbb E[h(X_2,X_1)]}{2} = \mathbb E[h(X_1, X_2)] = \theta $$

Thus we can just work with the kernel $\tilde{h}$ instead of $h$.

The generalization to kernels of order $r$ is easy: Let $S_r$ be the symmetric group on $r$ letters (i.e. the group of permutations), then we define:

$$ \tilde{h}(x_1,\dotsc,x_r) := \frac{1}{r!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_r} h(x_{\sigma(1)}, \dotsc, x_{\sigma(r)})$$

and work with $\tilde{h}$ instead of $h$.

Comment: Thanks, @air, that's very clear. So this works because $X_{i}$ are drawn iid, so we get the same value in both the symmetric and asymmetric expectations. I couldn't see that when I first read the wiki page.